# Insert row with another column containing the row's id, besides the id column

Tags: mysql

Here is a minimal version of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id int unsigned PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
    root_id int unsigned,
    parent_id int unsigned
);
```

The data is in a tree structure, so the `parent_id` field contains the obvious, and the `root_id` field contains the id of the root post, that is, the topmost post in the tree, the oldest ancestor in the tree.

Now, when I insert a new post that is itself the root of a new tree, the `parent_id` will be null, for it has no parent, but the `root_id` should refer to itself. Is there a way to do an insert that will put the same value of `id` into `root_id`? I'd like to avoid doing the insert, getting the new id and changing the root id with a second query, but maybe that's the only way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can make root_id and parent_id the same value to indicate the topmost item.  Look up triggers.

Comment: True, but that would complicate my apps logic, I'd have to do two ifs depending on if there is a root id, or if it's null.

Comment: I disagree. You would disallow nulls, making parent_id a required field.

Comment: But then I'd have to get the row's id both for the parent_id and the root_id, same problem.

Comment: You're making something into a "problem" that isn't really a problem. There are "problems" associated with NULLs that you might do well to avoid.  Under your scheme, the absence of a value in the parent_id field conveys meaning (i.e. new top-level posting).  In the schema I'm suggesting, the equality of root_id and parent_id signifies that fact.  If you can provide root_id in a trigger you can certainly provide parent_id too.  And then you have an affirmative way of indicating that a posting is top-level and you can avoid all NULL-related issues.

Comment: I understand your point now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
INSERT INTO
  posts
SET
  root_id = (SELECT Auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'posts');
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5833/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trigger to update the table instantly after an `insert`

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER update_root AFTER INSERT on posts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if NEW.parent_id IS NULL 
    then 
        SET NEW.root_id =  NEW.id;
    end if;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just thought of a neat one and tested it. It seems to work, but maybe under certain conditions it can go wrong?

```
INSERT INTO posts ( root_id, parent_id ) VALUES ( LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1, NULL );
```

Is there any problem or disadvantage to this?

Comment: What if the last insert was in a different table?